# How can I make a java method return an object found in a list of objects?

Tags: java, list, object, return-type, object-type

I have this code:

```
    public Task getTask(String taskID) {
        
        for (Task item : tasks) {
            if (item.getTaskID() == taskID) {
                return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Task is an object type, and "tasks" is a list containting all objects of type Task.

I want to iterate through the list and find the object where the taskID matches. This seems to work, but when I try to test or run, Eclipse tells me that this method "must return an a result of type Task".

I'm not sure what I have wrong. If each "item" is an item in the list, shouldn't it be of type Task?

I've tried iterating through the list by index numbers as well and that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I think there's a problem with the definition of `tasks`.  Can you show us that variable definition?

Comment: Alternately, after the final brace of the `for` loop, you should return `null` if no object is found.

Comment: The problem is that your method **must** return something every time it is called. The way it is currently written it doesn't return anything if no task with the specific `taskID` that you pass as parameter is in the list - but even then your method **must** return something (or throw an exception).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using '==' to compare strings, you can use the equals() method.
This is because '==' compares object references, not the contents of the strings themselves.

```
public Task getTask(String taskID) {
    for (Task item : tasks) {
        if (item.getTaskID().equals(taskID)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```